# Strange int Behavior. '==' not correctly working

Tags: java

I have this code that I've been working on for about half an hour now. It's EXTREMELY simple but it's just not working. I have a method that's supposed to return three numbers that add up to the parameter given. I want it random so I use the Random class. But first I have to make sure it's correct. If it's not correct. I just re-run the method again until it returns a correct value. But for some reason, I keep getting a StackOverflowException. It's really strange. The '==' operator is simply not working! Here's the full code that I'm using (I did simplify it so I can easily show it):

```
public static int[] getNumbersFor(int f)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int l = (r.nextInt(20) + 20) / 2;
    int a = l + l % 2;
    int[] i = new int[]
    {
        (int) (f - a / 2 - l % 2), 
        (int) (f + a), 
        (int) (f - a / 2 + l % 2)
    };
    int b = (i[0] + i[1] + i[2]);
    int c = ((i[0] + i[1] + i[2]) / 3);
    boolean d = i[0] + i[1] + i[2] == f / 3;
    System.out.println(f + ", " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ", " + d);
    return i[0] + i[1] + i[2] == f / 3 ? i : getNumbersFor(f);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] i = getNumbersFor(33);
    System.out.println(i[0] + ", " + i[1] + ", " + i[2]);
}
```

It's supposed to be correct! It's just not. I have no idea why it isn't correct! I was wondering if it had anything to do with my computer itself so [here's](http://pastebin.com/wuzt6Cus) (pastebin) what I get from the full log of `System.getProperties().list(System.out)`. If you need to know the output of this. Here's a little snippet of the error itself that I keep getting:

```
33, 14, 99, 33, false
33, 10, 99, 33, false
33, 14, 99, 33, false
33, 16, 99, 33, false
33, 20, 99, 33, false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:77)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:564)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:619)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:561)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
    at moretesting.NewClass.getNumbersFor(NewClass.java:16)
    at moretesting.NewClass.getNumbersFor(NewClass.java:17)
    at moretesting.NewClass.getNumbersFor(NewClass.java:17)
    at moretesting.NewClass.getNumbersFor(NewClass.java:17)
    at moretesting.NewClass.getNumbersFor(NewClass.java:17)
    ... (This is repeated TONS of times, I just omitted it)
```

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/iWckpMJc) the full log. (Again pastebin. It's EXTREMELY large, A few thousand lines!)

Comment: This code is a mess.  Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: Maybe the condition is never true? `20 + 99 + 33` doesn't equal `33 / 3`.

Comment: Your numbers always add up to 99. That's `f * 3` when you are checking for `f / 3`. If that helps.

Comment: "*The `==` operator is simply not working!*" Did you even check with a debugger before you say that? You will notice that the sum of your `int`s in the array is `f * 3` and not `f / 3`. Voting to close.

Comment: Oh my god. I'm extremely sorry guys! I misread it. I'm really sorry for my stupidness. Amir Afghani, What's messy about it? Maybe I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that recursion is really the way to solve this. At the very least, randomly guessing numbers until you happen to stumble upon a combination that adds up to your input seems hideously inefficient.

If you're just looking for three pseudo-random numbers that add up to the input parameter, why not just do something like this?

```
public static int[] getNumbersFor(int number)
{
    int firstMax = 0;
    int firstMin = 0;

    int secondMax = 0;
    int secondMin = 0;

    if (number > 100)
    {
        firstMax = 100;

        if (number > 200)
        {
            firstMin = number - 200;
        }
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    int firstRand = r.nextInt(firstMin, firstMax);

    int a = firstRand;

    int temp = number - a;

    if (temp > 100)
    {
        secondMax = 100;
        secondMin = temp - 100;
    }

    int secondRand = r.nextInt(secondMin, secondMax);

    int b = secondRand;

    int c = temp - b;

    return new int[] { a, b, c };
}
```

Comment: Oo, very interesting! Sadly, I seem to be getting an error from this. Specifically from the r.Next method. I'll just assume you mean the nextInt(...) method

Comment: Yes, sorry, `nextInt` is what I meant and I've edited my answer accordingly. I guess I was getting my Java and my C# confused. ;)

Comment: Well it works very well. Can you suggest a way for me to do it when a, b, and c cannot be more than 100 each? So it can't be like, 40, 64, 102. This is kinda what I'm going for.

Comment: That's a very good question. Depending on the range of numbers that could be passed in, that could lead to all sorts of difficulties. For instance, if you pass in a number greater than 300 then at least one number would have to be over 100 with my solution. Do you know the range of numbers that might be passed in?

Comment: Yes Each number cannot exceed 100. So the overall addition cannot be more than 300. Thank you for helping me out! It really means a lot to me!

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into account a maximum input of 300 and a maximum output of 100 for each of the three numbers.

Comment: I  tried this, and again, it didn't quite work. I just used this code [here](http://pastebin.com/3YJF2Ye6). It might be a bit more CPU intensive, but it get's the job done quite well. Thanks for the help though! I really learned!

Answer (score 3):

`==` is working fine, you're just comparing things that aren't equal.  Here's an evaluation of sample values from running your code:

```
i[0] + i[1] + i[2] == f / 3
26   + 47   + 26   == 33 / 3
99                 == 11
false
```

Every set of numbers produced followed this pattern: the numbers sum to 99, you compare that to 11, it recurses because the condition was false, then it stack overflows due to infinite recursion (it can't produce values that will pass the condition).

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I was dividing the wrong side of the equation. Really a stupid mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well this line of code is recursively calling your function.

```
return i[0] + i[1] + i[2] == f / 3 ? i : getNumbersFor(f);
```

carefully inspect your code and understand why the recursion never terminates.

When a function call is invoked, a stack frame is allocated on the call stack. The stack frame contains the parameters of the invoked method, its local parameters, and the return address of the method.
If there is no space for a new stack frame then, the StackOverflowError is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Use function recursion with caution. If you have verified that the recursion is implemented correctly, you can increase the stack’s size, in order to allow a larger number of invocations.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Thank you for pointing this out. I will definitely remember this next time!